# How can I tie value of a variable to the name of that variable?

Tags: python

I'm working on a homework assignment for an intro to programming class that is asking me to create a program that allows a user to input a list of values (rainfall in each of a 12 month period) and to calculate the total, median, and the lowest and highest values in the list.

What I have so far works, but I don't know how to make the program print the name of the month that the value is tied to. That is, if March had the lowest amount of rainfall, how do I tell it to print not just the integer that the variable `mar` represents, but the name of that variable as well? From what I can find online, it's being suggested that I should perhaps be using a dictionary instead of a list - but we don't cover dictionaries in class until next week, and the chapter of the book the excersise is from is all about lists, so I assume I'm supposed to find a way to do this with a list.

Here's my code so far:

```
def main():
    jan= float(input('Please enter January rainfall'))
    feb= float(input('Please enter Februrary rainfall'))
    mar= float(input('Please enter March rainfall'))
    apr= float(input('Please enter April rainfall'))
    may= float(input('Please enter May rainfall'))
    jun= float(input('Please enter June rainfall'))
    jul= float(input('Please enter July rainfall'))
    aug= float(input('Please enter August rainfall'))
    sep= float(input('Please enter September rainfall'))
    oct= float(input('Please enter October rainfall'))
    nov= float(input('Please enter November rainfall'))
    dec= float(input('Please enter December rainfall'))
    yearly_rainfall = [jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec]
    total = sum(yearly_rainfall)
    median = total / 12
    print('The total rainfall for the year is', total)
    print('The average monthly rainfall for the year is', median)
    print('The month with the lowest rainfall was', min(yearly_rainfall))
    print('The month with the highest rainfall was', max(yearly_rainfall))


main()
```

Comment: Why can't you store a separate list with the month names?

Comment: i thought of that, but i'm not sure how to tell it to pick the month name that corresponds to the correct variable

Comment: solving your question can be done in many different ways, you could for example read the docs on lists how to find a value in a list. or you could rethink your datastorage and use dicts.

Comment: @ElijahRyker. The [index](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) method of lists will find the index of a given value. (PS: strictly speaking, more than one month could have the lowest or highest rainfall).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply have a relationship between the min and the max value's index within the list to another list containing the month names.

```
calendarMonthNames = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
#Get the index of the min value and use that index value to get the month name.
print('The month with the lowest rainfall was', min(yearly_rainfall), ', and that month is', calendarMonthNames[yearly_rainfall.index(min(yearly_rainfall))])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I what i wanted to know. You're awesome!